# Python GDAL package missing header file when installing via pip

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to install gdal from pip `pip install gdal` inside a virtual environment (Ubuntu). It fails because it cannot find `cpl_port.h`

```
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2853:22: fatal error: cpl_port.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

However GDAL is installed correctly and the header file is located at `/usr/include/gdal/cpl_port.h`. Is there some environment variable for GDAL that needs to be set in order for pip to find the header files?

Answer (score 25):

As suggested in [the other thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/64244/13609), exporting some shell variables before running pip worked flawlessly. A path for `*_INCLUDE_PATH` can be found with `gdal-config --cflags`.

```
# GDAL library must have been installed
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev

# Set up pip and/or virtualenv stuff
...

# Now install Python binding for GDAL
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
pip install GDAL
```

Comment: This fixed it for me, but also see @Neil Smith's answer: in Ubuntu 14.04, you need to match the version of libgdal installed on the system.

Comment: Still think this is bug. gdal_wrap.cpp should #include "gdal/cpl_port.h" instead of just "cpl_port.h"

Comment: Definitely did NOT work for me. Still same cpl_port.h error. Using OpenSUSE

Comment: pip3 install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version)
Explicit version number should match your existing libgdal version.

Answer (score 8):

Tomyun's answer worked for me, with the proviso that you have to ensure that the version of GDAL-dev installed via `apt-get` matches the version being installed by `pip`.

For Ubuntu 14.04, the commands are:

```
# GDAL library must have been installed
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev

# Set up pip and/or virtualenv stuff
...

# Now install Python binding for GDAL
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
pip3 install GDAL=1.10.0
```

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04 too. For me it did not worked (I have no virtualenv). Only when I have changed the the last rowto this one:
sudo pip3 install  --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" GDAL==1.10.0

Comment: pip3 install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version) will work for all versions.

Answer (score 8):

Taken from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336153/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip#comment98474609_25283651), it solved my issue directly

```
pip3 install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version)
```

Explicit version number should match your existing libgdal version. –

Answer (score 5):

**Using PIP** :

```
pip install --no-install GDAL
```

Then cd into ENV/build/GDAL

```
python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=/usr/include/gdal
pip install --no-download GDAL
```

(Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769445)

**Using Buildout** :

```
[gdal-bindings]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
egg = GDAL==1.9.1
include-dirs = /usr/include/gdal
library-dirs = /usr/lib
```

Comment: This could also be `include-dirs=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Headers/` on OSX if you installed w/ Kyngchaos...

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this error when test installing in a virtual environment a package of mine that depends on GDAL. In this case the solution is to change the dependecy from `GDAL` to `pygdal` in the `install_requires` parameter in `setup.py`. Like so:

`install_requires=['pygdal'],`

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

I had to get the latest hearder versions for installing gdal 2.2.4 through pip:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgdal-dev
```

Before that, I was getting `extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3172:27: fatal error: cpl_vsi_error.h: No such file or directory`, even when including the correct "include" path to pip.

The the pip installation (in a virtualenv):

```
 pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" gdal
```

Answer (score -3):

try to do:
    brew install gdal

after that try again.

Comment: This answer would be much more helpfull if you explained OP what is wrong in his case and in what way your snippet solves the problem, and what are the prerequisites for brew to work.

Comment: `brew` is Mac-only whilst the OP uses Ubuntu