# Using pip to install modules in python failing

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip, gdal

I'm having trouble installing python modules using pip. Below is the output from the command window:

Note that I installed pip immediately before trying to install GDAL module.

I am on a w7 64bit machine running python 2.7

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jnunn\Desktop>python get-pip.py
Downloading/unpacking pip
Downloading pip-1.2.1.tar.gz (102Kb): 102Kb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package pip

warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.txt' found under directory
'docs\_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build\_sources'
Installing collected packages: pip
Running setup.py install for pip

warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.txt' found under directory
'docs\_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build\_sources'
Installing pip-script.py script to C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\Scripts
Installing pip.exe script to C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\Scripts
Installing pip.exe.manifest script to C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\Scripts
Installing pip-2.7-script.py script to C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\Scripts
Installing pip-2.7.exe script to C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\Scripts
Installing pip-2.7.exe.manifest script to C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\Scripts
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...

C:\Users\jnunn\Desktop>pip install gdal
Downloading/unpacking gdal
Downloading GDAL-1.9.1.tar.gz (420kB): 420kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package gdal

Installing collected packages: gdal
Running setup.py install for gdal
building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo
/Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I
C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\include -IC:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\PC -IC:\Python26\ArcGIS1
0.1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include /Tpextensions/gdal_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\te
mp.win32-2.7\Release\extensions/gdal_wrap.obj
gdal_wrap.cpp
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) :
warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled
. Specify /EHsc
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(2853) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file
: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory
error: command '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\c
l.exe"' failed with exit status 2
Complete output from command C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe -c "import se
tuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\jnunn\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build\\gdal\\setu
p.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'
))" install --record c:\users\jnunn\appdata\local\temp\pip-f7tgze-record\install
-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win32-2.7

copying gdal.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7

copying ogr.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7

copying osr.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7

copying gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7

copying gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo

copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo

copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo

copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo

copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo

copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo

copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo

copying osgeo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\osgeo

running build_ext

building 'osgeo._gdal' extension

creating build\temp.win32-2.7

creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release

creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\extensions

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
/MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -IC:\P
ython26\ArcGIS10.1\include -IC:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\PC -IC:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\
lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include /Tpextensions/gdal_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.w
in32-2.7\Release\extensions/gdal_wrap.obj

gdal_wrap.cpp

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : war
ning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(2853) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'c
pl_port.h': No such file or directory

error: command '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.ex
e"' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\us
ers\\jnunn\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build\\gdal\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(_
_file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\u
sers\jnunn\appdata\local\temp\pip-f7tgze-record\install-record.txt --single-vers
ion-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jnunn\appdata\local\
temp\pip-build\gdal
Storing complete log in C:\Users\jnunn\pip\pip.log

C:\Users\jnunn\Desktop>
```

I have tried to use easy_install before too, and it came back with a common error to this:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : war
ning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(2853) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'c
pl_port.h': No such file or directory

error: command '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.ex
e"' failed with exit status 2
```

Plus the following additional pip.log:

```
    Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 107, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 261, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1166, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options)
File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 589, in install
cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 612, in call_subprocess
% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\jnunn\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build\\gdal\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r    \n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\jnunn\appdata\local\temp\pip-f7tgze-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jnunn\appdata    \local\temp\pip-build\gdal
```

Comment: you could install `gdal` using binary installer from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Perhaps this forum post can help you out: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769445

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue looks very similar to [Python GDAL package missing header file when installing via pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336153/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip) which seems to have working [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12550704/565525).

Usual problem with python libraries that have CPython extensions is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629497/565525) and  solution is often:

> install library by downloading and running windows binary package.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way (as suggested by J.F. Sebastian) is to install from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Python thinks to be installed on C:\Python\ but this is not true as it is inside portablepython directory.
I resolved this using a link.

For instance my portablepython directory (or kivy directory in example) is this:

```
C:\Users\blabla.KMS\kivy-1.8.0-py3.3-win32\Python33
```

enter dos prompt and type:

```
mklink /d c:\Python33\ C:\Users\blabla.KMS\kivy-1.8.0-py3.3-win32\Python33\
```

than you can go inside c:\Python33\Scripts and use PIP or easy_install
finally you can delete the link using:

```
rmdir Python33
```

Cool! I installed Django on kivy!

Comment: `mklink /d c:\Python33\ C:\Users\blabla.KMS\kivy-1.8.0-py3.3-win32\Python33\` is generating an error for me: `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` do you know why? im using the following: `mklink /d "C:\Python27\" "C:\Users\USR01\virtualenvs\env1\"` as administrator...

Comment: this cant work. 1) c:\Python33\ already exists so it will throw error when trying to link c:\Python33\ to your virtual environment, and vice versa, when you try to link c:\Python33\ to your virtual environment it will throw an error as the virtual environment is already created.

Comment: I used this method to install packages inside portablepython and kivy, so in my case the directory c:\Python33\ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Python problem, but an issue with the compilation of the sources on Windows.

I assume that you followed the [installation instructions](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) and installed the GDAL binaries first, with the header files ?

Moreover, you can check the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336153/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip) which points to a [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769445) that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but i needed to install 'ebooklib' module, which is not in the list of modules at [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal). At the same time i had this module downloaded. But installation with ebooklib's setup.py failed with
`error: command '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.ex
e"' failed with exit status 2`
Finnally, i've installed all the dependent modules separately, from lfd.uci.edu, and after that installing with setup.py was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to install ipython without anaconda. First pip could not find 'cl.exe' when doing pip install jupyter and after adding to PATH, i got the failed with exit status 2 error.

You could try playing around with VS files to get it to work, but the easiest way around it for me was to:

1) Download the .tar.gz file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi
2) extract in a folder
3) run setup.py in the extracted folder from cmd:

```
c:\> cd <wherever your extracted folder is from .tar.gz that contains setup.py>
c:\<yourcdhere>>python setup.py install
```

note if, like me, you don't have python in the PATH because you have python 32b and 64b for different things, you will have to point to python manually (change second command to):

```
c:\<yourcdhere>>pythoninstallpath\python setup.py install
```

and it will automatically copy the library and install all its dependencies in python install location under the appropriate lib folder.

So that you can see how it worked, here it is for me. but change directories to match whatever you are using:

i have the extracted folder with ipython's setup.py at "L:\python\py27_32b\ipython-5.3.0"
and python installed at "L:\python\py27_32b\install"

```
c:\users\vlox>L:
L:\>cd "python\py27_32b\ipython-5.3.0"
L:\python\py27_32b\ipython-5.3.0>L:\python\py27_32b\install\python setup.py install
```

and voila!

hope this helps