# Using pip in windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

I installed [distribute](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute) and [pip](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip) using the links I have just given. I also installed the  [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29).  However when I try to use pip.exe I get

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package is not sufficient to compile packages. You need to install a *compiler*, not just the support files.

There are three ways to do this:

1. Install Visual C++.
2. Use mingw's port of gcc instead of Visual C++.
3. Use cygwin's port of gcc instead of either, and a cygwin build on Python instead of the native one.

---

If you want to go with option 1, you need to install Visual C++ itself. The free version should work just as well as the paid version, as long as you're not going to build binary packages to redistribute to others. Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to find the 2008 version anymore. As of May 2013, [the download page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads) only has 2010 and 2012.

When you install this, it will create a batch file called `vcvarsall.bat` (not `vcvarshall.bat`!), and give you the option of putting that batch file in your PATH. Running that batch file sets up a DOS prompt for building with that version of Visual C++. (This is handy if you have multiple versions of Visual C++, or other compilers, around.) If you skip that option, you will have to do it manually.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) shows how to use a newer Visual Studio with older Python, and also shows how to point distutils at a `vcvarsall.bat` that's not on your PATH, and has links to a whole lot of other relevant questions and blog posts.

---

Many people find option 2 simpler. Install [`mingw`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/), modify your PATH in the environment to include `C:\MinGW\bin` (or wherever you choose to install it), and pass `-c mingw32` whenever you run a `setup.py` script.

The problem is that it's not as clearly documented how to tell `easy_install` and `pip` to use mingw instead of VC++. To do that, you need to find or create a `distutils.cfg` file, find or create a `[build]` section within it, and add `compiler=mingw32`. Not too hard. [This blog post](https://zignar.net/2012/06/17/install-python-on-windows/) looks like it explains things pretty well, or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5051281/908494).

---

Option 3 is by far the simplest. Install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), tell it to install the Python and gcc packages, and you're done.

The problem is that you don't have native Windows Python, you have a Unix Python running in a fake Unix environment on top of Windows. If you like Cygwin, you'll love this; otherwise, you won't.

Comment: Thanks. I went for option 2 and got as far as trying "pip.exe install cython". However I get the error "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Pytho
n27\PC -c c:\users\marshall\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-clifford\cython\Cython\
Plex\Scanners.c -o c:\users\marshall\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-marshall\cython\cython\plex\scanners.o

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Comment: Apparently this is a problem in python as gcc 4.7.0 removed this option. The answer is to edit the file C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py and just delete the -mno-cygwin option wherever you see it.

Comment: The web installer for Visual C++ 2008 express can be found here: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279 - for now at least.

Comment: @mwotton You saved my day! Now M2Crypto is finally compiled!

Answer (score 4):

You'll receive such error only for packages (or one of package's dependencies) that has [CPython](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) extensions. Pip internally:

- downloads the source
- runs [distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/) `python setup install`
- `install` prepares setup files and tries to build [CPython](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) extensions in [windows](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.msvccompiler) environment
- windows environment calls MS Visual Studio `vcvarsall.bat` script which setups DOS environment variables to enable MS Visual Studio's C compiler in the shell
- if `vcvarsall.bat` is not found - you'll get this message

## Usual solution

For python libraries which have [CPython](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) extensions that are portable on windows, it is usual to have **windows binary package**, which are downloadable from pypi or library web site.

In such cases it is more suitable (and painless) to **install library by downloading and running windows binary package**.

There is a feature request for `pip` to [Add support for installation of binary distutils packages on Windows](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/520).

## New way to do it - wheels

Thanks to comment from @warren-p: *That feature request has been superseeded by Wheels support in PIP.*

Official description: *A wheel is a ZIP-format archive with a specially formatted filename and the .whl extension.*

As I have understood, if there is windows binary package with extension .whl then start by installing wheel first:

```
# Make sure you have the latest pip that supports wheel
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install wheel
```

and then install .whl like this:

```
pip install full-path-or-url-to-your-library.whl
```

References:

- [pythonwheels.com](http://pythonwheels.com)
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel
- http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: That feature request has been superseeded by Wheels support in PIP.  http://pythonwheels.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can download Visual Studio 2008 Express SP1 from

http://visual-studio-2008.en.malavida.com/

You can deselect the two add to browser options it offers.

Answer (score 0):

I found these links on microsoft.com that still work to Install Visual C++.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/5/8B5804AD-4990-40D0-A6AA-CE894CBBB3DC/VS2008ExpressENUX1397868.iso

2008 SP1 here

http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/8/E/E8EEB394-7F42-4963-A2D8-29559B738298/VS2008ExpressWithSP1ENUX1504728.iso