# Python GDAL: pip install --no-install GDAL fails

Tags: python, virtualenv, gdal

I am trying to install GDAL in virtual environment based on the various [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336153/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip) out there.

However the download itself already fails:

```
$ pip install --no-install GDAL
```

Here is the pip.log

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/Users/test/venv/bin/pip run on Sun Jun  2 15:35:15 2013
Downloading/unpacking GDAL

  Running setup.py egg_info for package GDAL

    running egg_info
    writing pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

      File "/Users/test/venv/build/GDAL/setup.py", line 267, in <module>

        ext_modules = ext_modules )

      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

        dist.run_commands()

      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

        self.run_command(cmd)

      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

      File "<string>", line 14, in replacement_run

      File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 259, in find_sources

        mm.run()

      File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 325, in run

        self.add_defaults()

      File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 361, in add_defaults

        sdist.add_defaults(self)

      File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 211, in add_defaults

        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')

      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command

        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized

        self.finalize_options()

      File "/Users/test/venv/build/GDAL/setup.py", line 164, in finalize_options

        self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')

      File "/Users/test/venv/build/GDAL/setup.py", line 144, in get_gdal_config

        return fetch_config(option)

      File "/Users/test/venv/build/GDAL/setup.py", line 97, in fetch_config

        raise gdal_config_error, e""")

      File "<string>", line 4, in <module>

    __main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    running egg_info

writing pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/Users/test/venv/build/GDAL/setup.py", line 267, in <module>

    ext_modules = ext_modules )

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "<string>", line 14, in replacement_run

  File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 259, in find_sources

    mm.run()

  File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 325, in run

    self.add_defaults()

  File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 361, in add_defaults

    sdist.add_defaults(self)

  File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 211, in add_defaults

    build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command

    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/Users/test/venv/build/GDAL/setup.py", line 164, in finalize_options

    self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')

  File "/Users/test/venv/build/GDAL/setup.py", line 144, in get_gdal_config

    return fetch_config(option)

  File "/Users/test/venv/build/GDAL/setup.py", line 97, in fetch_config

    raise gdal_config_error, e""")

  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>

__main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

----------------------------------------

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/test/venv/build/GDAL

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 266, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1057, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 236, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/Users/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 662, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/test/venv/build/GDAL
```

What am I missing?

Comment: for me helped reciept from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353962/pip3-gdal-install-failed-on-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error/52245969#52245969

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround to that problem is to

1. Download [GDAL Complete](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL_Complete-1.10.dmg) from [this site](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks)
2. Install GDAL Complete.pkg
3. Go to `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/` and copy all files in there
4. Go to your virtual environment's sites-packages `/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and paste the copied files in there

Comment: So to confirm. The gdal files must be stored in the directory of the interpreter selected for a given script? For instance if the interprester I am using too run a script is held in `~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe` , where would I put the GDAL files? I am quite fuzzy with how this all works so I am sorry if this is not an intelligent question.

Answer (score 13):

The workaround given by @user1738154 didn't work as expected for me so went ahead and installed GDAL using [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh) then using pip into my Virtual environment.

```
    $ brew install gdal
    (venv)$ pip install GDAL
```

Everything compiled and ran like a charm.

Comment: This worked wonderfully, thanks!  Please be sure to do a "brew update" as the lzip package has been reved from 1.14 to 1.15 in the latest GDAL recipe.

Answer (score 1):

after install gdal using these steps on host:

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

After that use

```
pip install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version) --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal"
```

This should work like charm