# pip3 GDAL install failed on Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python-3.x, centos, pip, python-3.4, gdal

I have a requirements.txt with python3 package that is used to deploy a webapp that uses GDAL. When I try to install the requirements.txt using `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`, it fails on per the below error. I'm on Centos 7.

I've tried (all in sudo su -)

> pip3 install --global-option=build_ext
>   --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" GDAL==2.2.4
>
> pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
>
> pip3 download GDAL
>
> yum install gdal-devel gcc
>
> pip3 install GDAL

ERROR:

```
Collecting GDAL
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/31/2e05c1be3196126fa04028aed51489f40ceea77e8361a80bc8b00fc463db/GDAL-2.3.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lriy4brt/GDAL/setup.py", line 153, in fetch_config
        p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 856, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1464, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../apps/gdal-config'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lriy4brt/GDAL/setup.py", line 240, in get_gdal_config
        return fetch_config(option, gdal_config=self.gdal_config)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lriy4brt/GDAL/setup.py", line 157, in fetch_config
        raise gdal_config_error(e)
    __main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../apps/gdal-config'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lriy4brt/GDAL/setup.py", line 153, in fetch_config
        p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 856, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1464, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lriy4brt/GDAL/setup.py", line 435, in <module>
        setup(**setup_kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 131, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 278, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 293, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 524, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 560, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 36, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_ext()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 119, in _add_defaults_ext
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lriy4brt/GDAL/setup.py", line 290, in finalize_options
        self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lriy4brt/GDAL/setup.py", line 246, in get_gdal_config
        return fetch_config(option)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-lriy4brt/GDAL/setup.py", line 157, in fetch_config
        raise gdal_config_error(e)
    __main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-lriy4brt/GDAL/
```

Comment: Do you have script `gdal-config` in `$PATH`?

Comment: No I don't. Any tips on creating that? I'm on a remote VM, on my local I was able to install no problem

Comment: You don't create the script — it must be installed with the library. Something like `yum install gdal` or `libgdal`, I'm not sure about the name of the package.

Comment: I've tried numerous packages like gdal-devel, gdal, libgdal, but they just keep saying no package gdal available. Can't seem to find the right name through google search either.

Answer (score 0):

for me helped

```
sudo yum install gdal
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum install gdal-python
```

you can find links to repositories for different os here
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries

and some recipes here
http://www.enhgo.com/code/pip-install-gdal-linux/