# Having trouble installing GDAL for python

Tags: python, pip, gdal

Let me start by saying that I have searched for help this problem and gone through the numerous threads that I have found, and none of them have worked, or I wasn't able to understand what they are saying to do.

Once such thread is here: [Python GDAL package missing header file when installing via pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336153/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip)

I was able to run

```
pip install --no-install GDAL
```

But then I was instructed to "cd into ENV/build/GDAL".  I know what cd means but I have no idea where this /ENV/build/GDAL diretory would be located and there is no more information about it in the post, or in the post that it references.

The core problem is just that I want to install GDAL for use in Python.  I tried

pip install GDAL, and it failed with this output:

```
    Collecting GDAL
  Using cached GDAL-2.0.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: GDAL
  Running setup.py install for GDAL
    Complete output from command c:\users\isaac\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Isaac\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-4kmkv1_4\\GDAL\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Isaac\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-fxko2gfx-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    copying gdal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
    copying ogr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
    copying osr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
    copying gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo
    copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo
    copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo
    copying osgeo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo
    Fixing build\lib.win32-3.5\gdal.py build\lib.win32-3.5\ogr.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osr.py build\lib.win32-3.5\gdalconst.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\gdal.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\gdalconst.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\gdal_array.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\ogr.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\osr.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\__init__.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    Fixing build\lib.win32-3.5\gdal.py build\lib.win32-3.5\ogr.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osr.py build\lib.win32-3.5\gdalconst.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\gdal.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\gdalconst.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\gdal_array.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\ogr.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\osr.py build\lib.win32-3.5\osgeo\__init__.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Command "c:\users\isaac\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Isaac\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-07o7k41s\\gdal\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Isaac\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-640gw1ah-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Isaac\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-07o7k41s\gdal
```

Can someone please help me with this? I'm completely lost and have no idea what to do about this.

I'm wondering if maybe it's because my python installation is in a funny place? It's installed at C:\Users\Isaac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\, which is where it was placed when I installed PyCharm, but that folder and the /Scripts/ folder inside are in my PATH.

Edit: After a bit more research I'm wondering if it's because I'm using Python 3.5? I'll try rolling back to Python 3.4 and see if it changes anything

Edit 2: Nope, no luck, it still fails and tells me

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)
```

I tried to install Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 and it just told me that there was already a newer version on my computer.

Comment: Do refer to this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009506/unable-to-install-python-and-gdal-dll-load-failed

Comment: I tried running through that but it didn't seem to work. I'll give it another try tomorrow when I'm hopefully a little more clear-headed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to install such kind of libraries is `conda`. Get and install [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) as user, not root. Now, create a new environment and install `gdal` into it:

```
conda create -n gdal_test python=3.5
activate gdal_test
conda install gdal
```

You need to stay inside this shell window. i.e. th prompt should like this `(gdal_test)`. Start Python:

```
python
>>> import gdal
```

**Note**: On Linux and Mac OS X use `source activate gdal_test`.

To find out what versions of `gdal` are available, type:

```
conda search gdal
```

An output like this:

```
gdal

      ....

               2.0.0               np110py34_0  defaults
```

means `gdal 2.0.0` is available for Python 3.4 and needs NumPy 1.10.

Comment: you may need to *conda upgrade numpy* after you install gdal this way.  on my windows install, it downgraded numpy.

Comment: @user1269942 When you create a new environment there should be no downgrade, because there is no NumPy installed yet (in this environment).

Comment: OK, I see...cool.  I guess I always have sklearn/numpy etc installed no matter what.  Environments...sounds good for allowing other to reproduce your results.

Comment: Ok I'm not understanding this.  I ran through all of the steps and then tried to import gdal (In the same cmd window) and it still says "no module named gdal".  Also, am I installing gdal to a specific environment? How do I access this environment from my IDE? I just want it to be installed by default. Is it a whole new python installation? I'm very confused.

Comment: I installed numpy using conda first (which I can import), and then try to install gdal, but I get this: http://pastebin.com/YwtxUpNh

Comment: I am on Mac OS X. I can install `gdal` with Python 3.5. Seems like `gdal`  is not available for Windows and Python 3.5 yet. `conda search gdal`  shows you what is available.

Comment: So in this output (http://pastebin.com/KvZpDg1i), I assume the second column is an indicator of the python versions that it is available for? And so I would either have to roll back to Python 3.3, or roll back to Python 3.4 AND numpy 1.8? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This line `2.0.0 np110py34_0  defaults` says that you can use Python 3.4 `conda create -n gdal_test python=3.4` with NumPy 1.10 (will be installed automatically) and `gdal 2.0.0`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much for your help, and for showing me conda... I don't fully understand how it is so different from pip but this virtual environment thing is really nifty and I can see how it would be immensely useful.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows the easiest way to install GDAL is to use pre-built binaries unless you have special needs that require building GDAL from source. Apart from `conda`, as mentioned by @Mike Müller, there are three common sources for GDAL Windows binaries (with Python bindings):

- [Gohlke Pythonlibs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)
- [GISinternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php)
- [OSGEO4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/)

Comment: Using `pip install GDAL-2.2.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` from **Gohlke Pythonlibs** worked for me on _Python 3.6.5_. Thanks :D

Comment: @emi I'm using Python 3.6.5 64-bit and can't install GDAL. Can you elaborate on the steps you took?

Comment: @akinuri I simply runed `pip install GDAL-2.2.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` on my **cmd** under Windows 10. You have to download the *.whl* file first of course and make sure that you are on the same path than the *.whl*; you can download that file from [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal). What error do you are having?

Comment: @emi See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50721107/2202732). Although I managed to install GDAL, I couldn't use `gdal_translate`. I'm getting an error saying "module could not be loaded" (probably missing dll: ogr_FileGDB)

Comment: @akinuri Sorry, I have no idea what's going on with your code; I have no experience in using GDAL. I simply executed a copy and paste code and it was executed successfully. Maybe your are trying to execute an old code? Maybe if you does not use gdal_translate library on your code execution?

Comment: @emi Posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50761021/2202732) about my actual problem. I might just ditch GDAL for good :)

Answer (score 1):

To install GDAL on windows, you need to follow the below-mentioned step: -

1. You need to install GDAL wheel file using the link https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal . After visiting this link, download this file named "GDAL‑3.0.4‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl" since it worked for me and then use the command "pip install c:\Users........\GDAL‑3.0.4‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl" to successfully install GDAL which is the requirement of Geopandas.

NOTE: If the above-mentioned wheel file doesn't work for you, then try using alternate wheel files.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (for my Windows 7):
Download the wheel file for GDAL from the following link (it has up to Python 3.8)

http://pypi.naturalcapitalproject.org/simple/gdal/index.html

I downloaded the wheel file (GDAL-3.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl) which is suitable for Python 3.7 installed on Windows 64-bit.

Go to the scripts folder of the Python folder and install the wheel file:

pip install GDAL-3.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

If the downloaded wheel file is on a specific folder, add the path to the pip command, for example:

pip install c:/users/myaccount/desktop/GDAL-3.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Lastly, do not change the name of the downloaded wheel file.