# GDAL on Python 3.6.5 (64-bit)

Tags: python, windows, installation, gdal

I've been trying to install GDAL on Python 3.6.5 (64-bit) on Windows for the past hour, and nothing works.

I've visited some questions on SO, watched a video on YT, but none of them applies to my situation (which there's nothing special about it).

Can someone provide a step-by-step solution, preferably a tested one, so I can figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong?

I'm willing provide any OS setting info/screenshot if necessary.

---

**Update:** I'm trying to install GDAL to convert TIF (16-bit) files to JPG or PNG. Although I managed to install GDAL with the second method (at second try), I could not use `gdal_translate`. So not every GDAL lib/version works for me.

---

First method:

- [GDAL 2.3.0](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48950889/2202732))

  - Dependencies:

    - libgdal (2.3.0 or greater) and header files (gdal-devel) (where/how do I get this?)
    - [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) (1.0.0 or greater) and header files (numpy-devel)
  - Requires "GDAL Windows Binaries". A Google search led me to this: [DownloadingGdalBinaries – GDAL](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries#Windows)

    - Tried [GISInternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/) -> [Releases](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php) -> [release-1911-x64-gdal-2-3-0-mapserver-7-0-7](http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-x64-gdal-2-3-0-mapserver-7-0-7.zip)
    - Downloaded `"gdal-203-1911-x64-core.msi"` and `"GDAL-2.3.0.win-amd64-py3.4.msi"`. (The latest release is for python 3.4?)
    - Installed `"gdal-203-1911-x64-core.msi"` to `"C:\Program Files\GDAL"`.
    - In README, it says

      > Add the installation directory bin folder to your system PATH...
      >
      > C:\gdalwin32-1.7\bin

      There is no `"bin"` folder in `"C:\Program Files\GDAL"`. Folders in GDAL dir: `"csharp"`, `"gdal-data"`, `"gdalplugins"`, `"license"`, `"projlib"`. So ...?

      I'm not even going to finish this because it seems outdated (I've emailed it's author about the description, so I hope it gets fixed). I followed the other steps, but it didn't work, obviously. Feel free to try it out.

---

Second method:

- [Gohlke Pythonlibs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34419524/2202732))

  - Downloaded `"GDAL-2.2.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"`
  - At the top of the page, it says (I probably missed this in the first try)

    > Many binaries depend on numpy-1.14+mkl and ...

    So I've downloaded `"numpy-1.14.4+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"` (it's in the same page)
  - Installed them:

    `pip install numpy-1.14.4+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

    `pip install GDAL-2.2.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

    and it worked (though I'm getting missing dll (ogr_FileGDB) error when using `gdal_translate`, so not using this)

---

I'll be updating this with the methods I've tried.

Comment: show your errors better

Comment: @zimdero There are multiple ways to install GDAL, and I've tried at least three of them. Which one do you want? I specifically said "preferably a tested one" because I want suggestions from experience. If we go examining the error messages, I believe we'll hit many walls because we don't even know if the installations I've tried applies to this specific python version.

Comment: Uninstall your Python installation.  Download and install the Anaconda installer from anaconda.com, it comes packages with Python and a lot of the most popular packages.  Install GDAL by running the command `conda install gdal`

Comment: Two steps: 1. install conda. 2. use `conda install -c conda-forge gdal`.

Comment: There are at least 4 methods listed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/installing-gdal-with-python-on-windows), which one did you try and what error came up with each one?

Comment: I'll be updating the question with the methods I've tried, but it takes time as I try them again. So I hope you guys revisit the question.

Comment: Try [pgmagick](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pgmagick): `from pgmagick import Image;Image('cmyk-16.tif').write('cmyk-16.jpg')` worked for me.

Comment: @cgohlke I've just done a quick [test](https://github.com/akinuri/dump/tree/master/python/tif-cmyk-16/pgmagick-image-open-test) with pgmagick and it seems to be working (were able to open the troublesome tif (cmyk/16) file). I've posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761021/how-to-open-a-tif-cmyk-16-bit-image-file) about opening the 16-bits tif files and I'll be updating it. I'll do further tests on Monday. If it all works out, I'll definitely ditch GDAL, and maybe Pillow too.

Answer (score 2):

The prebuild GDAL version from conda-forge works great on windows 64 bit python 3.6.5

You can install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) (or [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html))

After installing Anaconda, I usually use the Anaconda prompt instead of the regular windows command prompt.

**(Optional) If you would like to isolate this in a specific environment**

I would recomend using environments with anaconda so create some environment 
like this

`conda create --name gdal_env python=3.6.5`

`activate gdal_env`

Environments are not required, so you can skip this step and continue to installing gdal.

**Install gdal**

`conda install -c conda-forge gdal`

I have found conda-forge to be the (by far) easiest way to install GDAL on windows. If for some reason you are required to use another python distribution, i have found the prebuild binaries from here to work fine too https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ if you follow [this guide](https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2016/04/13/installing-gdal-ogr-for-python-on-windows/)

Comment: I was hopeful about Anaconda/Miniconda, but I've faced further problems. My main reason to install GDAL is to open 16-bit TIF files. I could not do this in Pillow, and it was suggested that GDAL can do it. I've succesfully installed GDAL (using miniconda), but `gdal_translate` threw some errors. TIF to JPEG gives `JPEG driver doesn't support data type UInt16` error. TIF to PNG gives `libpng: profile 'ICC Profile': 'CMYK': invalid ICC profile color space`. I thought I could fix these later (because they seem solvable), so I installed Pillow (I also need it).

Comment: `from PIL import Image` works fine, but `from PIL import ImageCms` threw an error: `ImportError: cannot import name '_imagingcms'`. I did not have this error with plain Python. I'm fed up with all these problems, so I'm dropping this for now. Although your answer and other comments solved **this** problem (so +1), my **actual** problem still remains. A side note: I've created a [repository](https://github.com/akinuri/dump/tree/master/tif-2-jpg) in case I (or someone else) revisit these problems.

Comment: Have you tried to add the scale option which maps it into 8 bit range?
If I add that convertion works fine.
`gdal_translate -scale -of JPEG cmyk-16.tif cmyk-16.jpg`
The scale options with zero arguments simply maps the 16 bit range into 8 bit. If you need some other scaling you can provide it as arguments to scale. I have just tried it on the images in your repo and it works fine

Comment: While scale alone works, it still has the warning, to get rid of that two, tell explicitly that you are converting to 8bit like this: `gdal_translate -scale -ot byte -of JPEG cmyk-16.tif cmyk-16.jpg`

Comment: Are you using GDAL of Anaconda? I've uninstalled it. I'm fixing the problematic TIFs (16-bit CMYK TIF) using Photoshop... After your reply, I thought that I don't need to associate GDAL with Python if I'm only gonna use `gdal_translate`. I've just installed `gdal-203-1911-x64-core.msi` from [here](http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-x64-gdal-2-3-0-mapserver-7-0-7.zip) and it didn't produce corrent images: [no-python](https://github.com/akinuri/dump/tree/master/tif-2-jpg/gdal/no-python) (repo update). Should I try different GDAL version?

Comment: I've tried a different GDAL (OSGeo4W) and the result is the same. So what exactly am I doing wrong? (Updated repo again)

Comment: I simply ran that command from within my Anaconda prompt, so it is GDAL installed with Anaconda. You can see the output images [here](https://ibb.co/kxZroT) and [here](https://ibb.co/eMm1No)

Comment: Are both of the the two links you've shared output images? Because the second one is the same as mine which is incorrect. I get the same result if I open the original image in Photoshop, invert colors, and move black towards white (through Levels). So can I say that GDAL doesn't convert correctly? If so, this has just became a GDAL-specific problem, and I might ask another question about this.

Comment: Yes, both are outputs. What do you expect the output image to be? Do you expect gdal to convert from cmyk to rgb? If so you could do it by 2 commands like this: First create an RGB tif from the CMYK one `gdal_translate -scale -ot byte -of GTIFF cmyk-16.tif cmyk-out.tif -co PHOTOMETRIC=CMYK`. Then create the RGB jpg from the newly created tif `gdal_translate -of JPEG cmyk-out.tif cmyk-out.jpg`. If this is not the behaviour you are expecting i think you should update your question with what you need from the output file. [This is the output](https://ibb.co/dKAzso)

Comment: I decided to post a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50761021/2202732) about this. I'd appreciate if you could take a look at it.