# Python GDAL package missing header file when installing via pip in Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am having a similar problem as to installing gdal using pip. However, I am using Windows 10.
The resulting error when I type `pip install gdal`in powershell is 
`extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(3085): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

I tried all the methods mentioned in the [original question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336153/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip) answer.

P.S.: I would have added this as a comment, but you need minimum 50 reputations and I  am new here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python GDAL package missing header file when installing via pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336153/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip)

Comment: I have seen that page. But all the answers are for ubuntu interface. I am working with Windows and somehow it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10 I was able to install into a virtual environment (`python -m venv myenvironment`). I did install [OSGeo4W64](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) but I didn't want to use that python because I'm using Anaconda python 3.6, so I did this from within my virtual environment:

`pip install gdal==2.2.2 --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:/OSGeo4W64/include/" --global-option="-LC:/OSGeo4W64/lib/"`

I also needed to set environment variables as discussed in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/#modify-windows-environment.

I haven't tested much yet, but so far `from osgeo import gdal` works

Comment: Just for comment, I did not found GDAL's headers for 64 bits distribution, so I needed to execute the following command: `pip install gdal==3.4.0 --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:/OSGeo4W/include/" --global-option="-LC:/OSGeo4W/lib/"`